# My layout of my dbc.Row dash bootstrap isn't displaying side by side

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm trying to create a dashboard to display bullet charts side by side, but they are showing vertically underneath each other. I'm using dash.bootstrap-components with plotly. A lot of people are saying in different forums that I should add the dbc.themes.bootstrap to styling for it to work but it isn't working for me -> (app = dash.Dash(**name**, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]).

Below is some of my code that I have that shows the charts going vertically. I want them to display side by side. When I first installed my packages, I was ablee to get it working, but once I upgraded pip and ran a few other packages and moved my folder to another location the layout seemed like it broke or something. Any suggestions. I do think that conda and pip installation have something to do with it im assuming bc I had issues with them and ran different packages with pip and conda. I also re-installed the dash_bootstrap_components. Any ideas what I should do.

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

  app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(html.H6("Title"),
             style={"text-align": "Center"}),
    html.Hr(),
    html.H1("Sub-Title"),
    dbc.CardHeader(
        dbc.Button(
            "Completed",
            color="link",
            id="buttonCompleted",
        )
    ),
    dbc.Collapse(
        dbc.CardBody("Chart goes here if needed."),
        id="collapseCompleted", is_open=False
    ),

    dbc.CardHeader(
        dbc.Button(
            "In Progress",
            color="link",
            id="buttonInProgress",
        )
    ),
    dbc.Collapse(
        dbc.CardBody(html.Div([
            dbc.Row(html.Div([
                dbc.Col(html.Div( [
                    dcc.Graph(id='bullet-chart1', 
                        figure=ff.create_bullet(
                            data, titles="title",
                            ranges='ranges',
                            measures='measures',
                            title=None, autosize=True,
                            width=450, height=300,
                        ),  
                    ), 
                ]), 
                ),

                dbc.Col(html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(id='bullet-chart2',
                        figure=ff.create_bullet(
                            data2, ranges='ranges',
                            measures='measures',
                            title=None, autosize=True,
                            width=450, height=300
                        )
                    ),
                ]), 
                ),
            ]),
            )
        ])),
        id="collapseInProgress", is_open=True
    ),

    dbc.CardHeader(
        dbc.Button(
            "Not Started",
            color="link",
            id="buttonNotStarted"
        )
    ),

    dbc.Collapse(
        dbc.CardBody("Chart goes here"),
        id="collapseNotStarted", is_open=False
    )
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything was good except I had the second dbc.Col outside of the row and had to bring it inside of the dbc.Row. I just rewrote it and started off with a basic string and found out why this was happening. Just had to bring up one above the parenthesis and added -> align="start", align="center" align="end" to each of the dbc.Col.